# Assigning Tags/Comments/Descriptions to Stock Apps in macOS

Tags: macos, finder, xcode, finder-tag, smart-folders

***TL;DR***- has anyone found a way to assign Tags or modify the Description/Comments on stock apps in macOS?

I'm currently working on creating Smart Folders based on Tags and it's working incredibly well, even better than I expected; discovered something about Xcode that I probably wouldn't have known about without having accidentally stumbled across it during this process [Can provide more details on the discovery if you are interested.]. Unfortunately, there are quite a few stock apps that do not allow manipulation of their information, namely Tags, Description, and Comments.

Has anyone found a way to assign Tags or modify the Description/Comments on stock apps in macOS?

Comment: You are going to need to specify exactly which stock apps and precisely what data for them.

Comment: It's unclear which tags, description, comments is being asked about. If it's app development, Stackoverflow would be a better place to ask it

Comment: Oh I’m just referring to the information that you can add to the Get Info window of an app in Finder. 

Will update the post so it’s clearer.